# What is the best way to get all the distinct values of columns by a list of them using typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

What is the best way to get all the distinct values of columns by a list of them using Typeorm?

I want to create a JSON object the key is the column name, and the value is a list of all the distinct values of it in the DB (PostgreSQL), the columns that I need come from a list.